# Position vector of the point dividing a straight line into given ratios

Tags: vectors, proof-explanation

I am confused about the following proof from a book.

> [image]
>
> In this figure, $P$ divides $AB$ internally in the ratio $m:n,$ i.e $AP
>  : PB = m : n$ ----(1)
>
> $OP = OA + AP$ ---- (1) and $OP = OB + BP$ ---- (2)
>
> $nOP = nOA + nAP$ ---- (3) and $mOP = mOB + mBP$ ---- (4)
>
> Adding (3) and (4), we get:
>
> $(m+n)OP=mOB+nOA+mBP+nAP$ ---- (5)
>
> This result holds for all values of $m$ and $n$.
>
> Here, $P$ divides $AB$ internally and we take both $m$ and $n$ to be positive.

How do we decide to take $m$ and $n$ to be positive?

> Since AP and BP are in opposite directions and $AP : PB = m : n$
>
> $nAP = mPB$
>
> Therefore, $(m+n)OP=mOB+nOA$ ---- (6)
>
> $$OP=\frac{mOB+nOA}{m+n}.$$

> Consider fig 3.1(a) and fig 3.1(b)
>
> [image]
>
> $AP = (m/n)PB$ and $AP$ and $BP$ are in the same direction.
>
> So, if the ratio $m:n$ is taken to be negative,

How and why are we taking the ratio $m:n$ to be negative?

> the expression $mBP+nAP$ in equation (6) will be zero. This as before we get:
>
> $$OP=\frac{mOB+nOA}{m+n}$$

Comment: In both cases, we have that $\vec{AP} = \frac mn\vec{PB}.$ 

In case 1, the diagram shows that $\vec{AP}$ and $\vec{PB}$ are in the same direction; thus, $\frac mn>0.$

In case 2, the diagram shows that $\vec{AP}$ and $\vec{PB}$ are in opposite directions; thus, $\frac mn<0.$